# Information on different aggregations - rolling up

Tags: tableau-api

Very bad title, I'm not sure how to frame this problem.

I have groups - A, B, C, and a bunch of information about that group.

I also have individuals - A1, A2, A3, etc. There's one field (let's call it eye colour) about individuals I want to grab.

It should be the case that this field is identical between all members of this group, but I can't be certain.

I want to be able to make a calculated field that returns 1 if the group contains an individual who has blue eyes, and then be able to use that field in the same row as the group.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I've misunderstood your question and lead you astray, I will delete this answer.

Create a calculated field called "Has Blue Eyes". Your formula should be something like `IF [eye color] = "BLUE" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"`

Then create another calculated field that uses the window_sum(sum([Has Blue Eyes]) function. There are two optional parameters to the function. They define the window offsets from your current row. Not knowing your table structure, I can't give you specifics. But you'd want to offset probably based on where the groups start and finish. The idea is that within your window, if the sum([Has Blue Eyes]) is greater than 0, at least one record in the window has blue eyes.

The Tableau online help at https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.html has a documentation on all of the table calculation functions. The window_sum() function is near the bottom.